# Deleted Ubuntu Partition - No Windows Recovery Disk

Tags: partitioning, windows

I shrunk my Windows partition. I took the unallocated space and installed Ubuntu on it.

Upon installation and updating, I realized I did not give myself enough space in the Ubuntu partition.

So, I went back into Windows, deleted the partition. I planned on re-shrinking and giving my Ubuntu partition about 100gb's. Upon restart, I got the fatal message:

Error, no partition found
Grub recovery...

Now, I have done some research. However, I do not have access to a Windows 7 recovery disk. I am currently running my system from a flash drive with a Ubuntu Live ISO.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just install Ubuntu again and at the end of the installation procedure, it will reinstall Grub (the boot loader). Upon reboot you should be able to boot into Windows or into your brand new Ubuntu.

Alternatively, there is a program called [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which can restore the MBR. Just [donwload it here](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home) and follow the instructions from  [the official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: The repair-disk is not in the repositories but it's even used in the community wiki.